# Does ZF(C) prove countable reflection?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Is the following a theorem of $\sf ZF(C)$?

**Countable reflection:** If $\phi$ is a sentence in which $W$ is not free, then:

$\phi \to \exists W: |W|= \omega \land \operatorname {Transitive}(W) \land \phi^W$

Where $\phi^W$ is the sentence obtained by merely bounding all quantifiers in $\phi$ by $ \in W$.

That is: every true sentence is reflected upon a countable transitive set.

So all true sentences are reflected upon some elements of $V_{\omega_1}$ (or $V_{\omega_2}$ in case of $\sf ZF$).

Comment: Yes, this follows from the reflection theorem and Lowenheim-Skolem.

Comment: The question twice mentions "formula" (once with the constraint that $W$ isn't free) and twice mentions "sentence(s)". I assume (and Monroe Eskew and Ali Enayat apparently also assumed) that you mean "sentence", because the version with "formula fails --- the formula $(\exists y)\ y=x$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Agreed! Thanks for the correction. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Monroe Eskew points out in his comment to the question, the positive answer is well-known for ZFC, thanks to the ZF reflection theorem and the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem (in the form: every model in a countable language has a countable elementary submodel). See, e.g., part (iii) of Theorem 12.14 in Jech's canonical textbook *Set theory, third millenial edition.*

Note that ZFC can be weakened in the above to ZF+ DC (DC = dependent choice) since it is well-known that in the presence of ZF, DC implies (and indeed is equivalent to, see, e.g., [Asaf Karagila's note](https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Lowenheim-Skolem-and-Choice.pdf)) the statement that every structure in a countable language has a countable elementary submodel.

> The point of this answer is to point out that even DC can be eliminated from the proof of countable reflection.

**Theorem.** ZF *proves every instance of countable reflection.*

Proof: In light of the fact that the Mostowski collapses can be carried out in ZF, and the constructible universe L satsifies ZFC (and therefore L satisfies "every model in a countable language has a countable elementary submodel), the proof is complete once we note:

$(*)$   For any set-theoretical sentence $\phi$, if $\phi$ has a transitive model, then the sentence "$\phi$ has a transtive model" holds in the constructible universe L.

The above statement, as far as I know, was first noted in a (famous) paper of Barwise and Fisher entitled "The Shoenfield Absoluteness Lemma" (Israel J. Math. 8 1970, pp.329-339) in which a fine-tuning of the Shoenfield Absoluteness Lemma is presented (in particular, it is shown that the Lemma can be proved without invoking DC).

More specifically, $(*)$ follows from Theorem 1b (page 336) of the Barwise-Fisher paper, which states that if $\phi$ has a transitive model $A$ with $\rho(A)=\alpha$ (where $\rho$ is the usual ordinal-valued rank function on sets), then there is a transitive model of $\phi$ in the $\kappa^{+}(\alpha)$-th level $L_{\kappa^{+}(\alpha)}$ of the constructible universe $L$, where $\kappa^{+}(\alpha)$ is the next admissible ordinal after the least admissible ordinal above $\alpha$.